# Getting message "Error while parsing file: The value of attribute "src" associated with an element type "content" must not contain the '<' character."

Tags: validation, epub

I am seeing this message: Error while parsing file: The value of attribute "src" associated with an element type "content" must not contain the '<' character.

My code is the same as in epubs without the problem.
Here code from the problem epub.

I'd appreciate suggestions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ncx version="2005-1" xmlns="http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/ncx/">
<head>
<meta content="726cb381-54ac-4020-a7f7-8fbfa2bcecff" name="dtb:uid"/>
<meta content="1" name="dtb:depth"/>
<meta content="0" name="dtb:totalPageCount"/>
<meta content="0" name="dtb:maxPageNumber"/>

</head>
<docTitle>
<text>Before the Mayflower: A History of the Negro in America, 1619-1962</text>
</docTitle>
<navMap>
<navPoint id="navPoint-1" playOrder="1">
   <navLabel>
    <text>Preface</text>
  </navLabel>
  <content src="Text/Preface.html"/>
</navPoint>
<navPoint id="navPoint-2" playOrder="2">
  <navLabel>
    <text>1. The African Past</text>
  </navLabel>
  <content src="Text/1.html"/>
</navPoint>
<navPoint id="navPoint-3" playOrder="3">
  <navLabel>
    <text>2. Before the Mayflower</text>
  </navLabel>
  <content src="Text/2.html"/>
</navPoint>
   <navPoint id="navPoint-4" playOrder="4">
```

Compared code from an epub which passed the validator test and the
 lines look exactly the same.